# Highlight or mark Filtered value in table when filter is applied - Tabulator Tables

Tags: javascript, tabulator

How to highlight filtered text in tabulator tables?

I am using tabulator general filter functionality and i want to highlight filtered text in tabulator table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to build a [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-custom) that used a regular expression or find and replace to look through the cells value and replace any areas that match the value of the filter input with a span containing that filtered value and adding a class on inline style to highlight the text.

You could then assign this formatter to the text containing cells.

You would also need to call the `redraw` function after triggering the filter to ensure that the formatters we retriggered to pick up the new filter value:

```js
table.redraw(true);
```

Comment: how can I get filter value in custom formatter?

Answer (score -2):

In your code  this function is used to set the filter when input is onkeyup

```
$("#tabulator-controls input[name=name]").on("keyup", function(){
        table.setFilter( "name", "like", $(this).val())
});
```

try to edit it to:

```
$("#tabulator-controls input[name=name]").on("keyup", function(){
        table.setFilter( "name", "like", $(this).val())

        // This should change the background of the line to red when filtered
        row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";

});
```

Comment: This will not work, the variable row has no context in that callback function